# Evaluating the infinite sum $\frac{1}{1!} + \frac{4}{2!} + \frac{7}{3!} + \frac{10}{4!} + \cdots + \frac{3n-2}{n!}+ \cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Evaluate the infinite sum:
>   $$\frac{1}{1!} + \frac{4}{2!} + \frac{7}{3!} + \frac{10}{4!} + \cdots + \frac{3n-2}{n!}+ \cdots$$

I can't really get far on this question. I thought it could be related to some sort of Maclaurin expansion.

Comment: HINT: $e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$ [[corrected]]

Comment: @TitoEliatron: Actually $e=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} =\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n!}$

Comment: UPS!!! My mistake with the initialization!!!!

Comment: *some sort of McLaurin expansion* --- If so, then your tag "algebra-precalculus" is definitely not appropriate!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Observe that

$$\frac{3n-2}{n!}=3\frac1{(n-1)!}-2\frac1{n!}$$ and you essentially face the sum of inverses of the factorials, which is well-known to be the constant $e$.

There is indeed a direct connection with the Maclaurin expansion of the exponential,

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ which is drawn from the facts that

$$(e^x)'=e^x$$ and $$e^0=1.$$